# How does Spring Data jpa know properties changed?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

So say I lookup an object from the repository. If I save this object immediately after lookup, Spring Data is smart enough not to update the database. If I change a property within this object and then save, spring data does an update. How does it know it needs to do an update or not?

Comment: Try doing `yourObject.getClass()`. What does that return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not provided by Spring Data, its a feature of your persistence framework (hibernate, openjpa, eclipselink,...).

Persistence providers enhance the domain objects with some "stuff" for optimization. Normally, this is done by so called runtime enhancement, so your class gets loaded inside of the application and enhanced there(runtime weaving).

Openjpa also allows build-time-enhancement, which means, the "openjpa-domain-extension-stuff" becomes added to your entities at compile time. (there is a maven goal in the openjpa plugin too) 
https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html

If you run mvn openjpa:enhance your simple domain will look now like the following: 
(I used jad to decompile the class, as it is to long to show all stuff inside, I copied the most relevant parts)

```
import org.apache.openjpa.enhance.*;
import org.apache.openjpa.util.IntId;
import org.apache.openjpa.util.InternalException;

public class Entity implements PersistenceCapable
{  
    public Integer getId()
    {  
        return pcGetid(this);
    }
    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        pcSetid(this, id);
    }
    ....
    .... 
    private static final void pcSetid(Entity entity, Integer integer)
    {  
        if(entity.pcStateManager == null)
        {  
            entity.id = integer;
            return;
        } else
        {  
            entity.pcStateManager.settingObjectField(entity, pcInheritedFieldCount + 3, entity.id, integer, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
    ....
    protected void pcClearFields()
    {  
        id = null;
    }

    public PersistenceCapable pcNewInstance(StateManager statemanager, Object obj, boolean flag)
    {  
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        if(flag)
            entity.pcClearFields();
        entity.pcStateManager = statemanager;
        entity.pcCopyKeyFieldsFromObjectId(obj);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

By manipulating your entity, the pcStateManager gets invoked. If you run a persist operation, the persistence framework checks the statemanager if there are changes within your entity and sends the update to the database if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't actually work directly on instances of your class. What it does is create a proxy that wraps the actual instance and delegates to it. This proxy holds the state of persistence of the underlying instance. In other words, it knows if the instance is in the same state as it is in the database as it is in memory.

If you invoke (certain) methods, it will consider itself dirty. The `EntityManager` will have to push those changes. If you don't, then it also knows that no changes need to be pushed.